# Need help to write a Jquery $.ajax request equivalent to an XHR request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Working XHR request that sends a file
with all required request headers set.

```
var upload = function (file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/Admin/Upload', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Filename', file.name);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('pageid', pageid);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('catid', catid);
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

Trying to get the below working (Using jQuery 1.7.2)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var upload = function (file, xhr) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: '/Admin/Upload',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Filename', file.name);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('pageid', pageid);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('catid', catid);

        },
        data: file,
        success: function (data) {

            alert('Load was performed.');
        }

    });
}
```

**Update:** 
Ok, so I have progressed a bit and the request now actually hits the action method,
however there is no data in the input stream and all the file key arrays are null,
so the actual file data does no appear to be going through. The request headers are coming through fine. The (data: file) is different I presume to xhr.send(file) ?

Now using this:

```
var upload = function (file) 
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "/Admin/Upload",
        headers: { catid: catid, pageid: pageid },
        processData: false,
        data: file,
        success: function (data) {

            alert('Load was performed.');
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: why have you defined xhr variable?  otherwise code looks good, it should set the request headers.

Comment: @gk Yeah I removed them now, the request gets through to my action method on the server now but there is no file data coming through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also set `contentType` to `false` and `type` to `'POST'`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/Upload",
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { catid: catid, pageid: pageid },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: file,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope, still source stream is empty. ContentLength = 0.

Comment: What is your `file` like to be?

Comment: @LaserBeak I mean the `file` variable, what is it?

Comment: A file var is from running a for loop on a file array (dataTransfer.files) that was created on a canvas Drop event.         dropzone.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            processFiles(event.dataTransfer.files);

        }, true);  The upload works normally when I use xhr.send(file), so the file data is valid.

Comment: @LaserBeak You also need to set the type to POST, try again.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thanks. Thought it was on by default Douugh!

Comment: @LaserBeak The default is `GET`. Glad to help~